# How to convert small jQuery extensions (functions) to modular javascript?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm in the process of updating an app away from jQuery and into vanilla JS using webpack (via Rails framework and webpacker gem).  I had several helper functions in jQuery that I implemented as extensions, but I'm not sure what the best approach is for migrating these to modular javascript.

This simple one allows me to increment/decrement text values in an element.

With HTML `<div id="counter">1</div>` I would increment it via `$("#counter").increment()` and it would update the value from 1 to 2.  Works very well, and allows me to use this function anywhere.

```
# jquery extension
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn, {
  increment(param) {
    return this.each(function() {
      const $element = $(this)

      if (param) {
        $element.text(param)
      } else {
        const $value = parseInt($element.text())
        if ($value !== NaN) {
          $element.text($value + 1)
        }
      }
      return $element
    })
  }
})
```

However, with my move to webpacker and modular JS, I think I'm supposed to wrap this into a module (file) and then import it everywhere I want to use it.

```
export default class Counter {
  increment(elementOrId) {
    const element = (elementOrId instanceof HTMLElement) ? elementOrId : document.getElementById(elementOrId)

    const currentCount = parseInt(element.text())
    if (currentCount !== NaN) {
      element.text(currentCount + 1)
    }

    return element
  }

  decrement() { ... }
}
```

And then using it in another JS module (file):

```
import Counter from "counter"

element = document.getElementById("counter")
Counter.increment(element)
```

That seems like a lot of steps for something as small as some helper methods.

However, I think JS libraries like lodash are structured like this, where it's the lodash class (`_`) and it just has a bunch of useful misc helper methods.

Is that the standard JS modular approach I should implement for my own custom helper methods?  Build a JS class and put all my methods into it like this?

Comment: I think it comes down to personal preference - you could create a class for each of you helper methods / or your could create one helper class with all your methods in it. I don't think there is a 'right' way to do it.